# How to use feign interceptor / decoder to log request - response in custom format?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm developing a custom logging framework for springboot to log rest-template requests and response and is working fine. Am trying to implement the same for 'Feign-Client' and am faced with couple of issues.

1. For request logging, am leveraging `FeignRequestInterceptor` and it is working fine, only problem here is I cannot retrieve the full request URL.
   Below method is giving me only relative URL.

   ```
   requestTemplate.url()
   ```
2. To log the response, only way i could find was the `ResponseDecoder`. There I'm able to retrieve everything other than the payload. When accessing the payload from

   ```
   InputStream is = response.body().asInputStream();
   String payload = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
   ```

This method works, but the original stream is closed because of which logging happens fine, but client is throwing exception when returning response.

> 'trying to open closed stream'

I would like suggestions if there are better ways of logging request response in Feign similar to spring rest-template. Or if the method I have adopted is fine, help me resolve the problems above.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a custom `feign.Logger` instance to handle this.  There are two built in, `JavaLogger` which uses `java.util.logging` and `Slf4JLogger` that uses `slf4j`.  You can create your own logger implementation by extending `feign.Logger` and registering it as a `@Bean`.

That logger should be picked up by Spring and registered with your `FeignClient`.  Here is the `Logger` base class to get you started:

```java
protected abstract void log(String configKey, String format, Object... args);
```

Create your own instance, implement this method and it will be called before the request and after the response is returned.  No need to update the interceptor or create a response decoder.

Answer (score 0):

in your RestConfiguration you need to up default level of logging feignClient and override by @Bean feignLogger like:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = [Application::class])
class RestConfiguration: WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun feignLoggerLevel(): Logger.Level {
        return Logger.Level.FULL
    }

    @Bean
    fun feignLogger(): Logger {
        return FeignClientLogger()
    }
}
```

and implement your logger (logbook format):

```
import feign.Logger
import feign.Request
import feign.Response
import feign.Util.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class FeignClientLogger : Logger() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    override fun logRequest(configKey: String?, logLevel: Level?, request: Request?) {
        if (request == null)
            return

        val feignRequest = FeignRequest()
        feignRequest.method = request.httpMethod().name
        feignRequest.url = request.url()
        for (field in request.headers().keys) {
            for (value in valuesOrEmpty(request.headers(), field)) {
                feignRequest.addHeader(field, value)
            }
        }

        if (request.requestBody() != null) {
            feignRequest.body = request.requestBody().asString()
        }

        log.trace(feignRequest.toString())
    }

    override fun logAndRebufferResponse(
        configKey: String?,
        logLevel: Level?,
        response: Response?,
        elapsedTime: Long
    ): Response? {
        if (response == null)
            return response

        val feignResponse = FeignResponse()
        val status = response.status()
        feignResponse.status = response.status()
        feignResponse.reason =
            (if (response.reason() != null && logLevel!! > Level.NONE) " " + response.reason() else "")
        feignResponse.duration = elapsedTime

        if (logLevel!!.ordinal >= Level.HEADERS.ordinal) {
            for (field in response.headers().keys) {
                for (value in valuesOrEmpty(response.headers(), field)) {
                    feignResponse.addHeader(field, value)
                }
            }

            if (response.body() != null && !(status == 204 || status == 205)) {
                val bodyData: ByteArray = toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream())
                if (logLevel.ordinal >= Level.FULL.ordinal && bodyData.isNotEmpty()) {
                    feignResponse.body = decodeOrDefault(bodyData, UTF_8, "Binary data")
                }
                log.trace(feignResponse.toString())

                return response.toBuilder().body(bodyData).build()
            } else {
                log.trace(feignResponse.toString())
            }
        }
        return response
    }

    override fun log(p0: String?, p1: String?, vararg p2: Any?) {}
}

class FeignResponse {
    var status = 0
    var reason: String? = null
    var duration: Long = 0
    private val headers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var body: String? = null

    fun addHeader(key: String?, value: String?) {
        headers.add("$key: $value")
    }

    override fun toString() =
        """{"type":"response","status":"$status","duration":"$duration","headers":$headers,"body":$body,"reason":"$reason"}"""
}

class FeignRequest {
    var method: String? = null
    var url: String? = null
    private val headers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var body: String? = null

    fun addHeader(key: String?, value: String?) {
        headers.add("$key: $value")
    }

    override fun toString() =
        """{"type":"request","method":"$method","url":"$url","headers":$headers,"body":$body}"""
}
```